# How to consume REST in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Using Java tools,

```
wscompile for RPC
wsimport for Document
etc..
```

I can use WSDL to generate the stub and Classes required to hit the SOAP Web Service.

But I have no idea how I can do the same in REST.
How can I get the Java classes required for hitting the REST Web Service.
What is the way to hit the service anyway?

Can anyone show me the way?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048091/generic-open-source-rest-client

Comment: This like will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221442/rest-clients-for-java

Comment: Guys... I don't want to hit the Web Service using URLs. I want to hit using my Java Classes. Is there a way?

Comment: check this 2 line of code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916169/how-to-consume-rest-in-java/48030636#answer-48030636

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Working example, try this:

```
package restclient;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class NetClientGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:3002/RestWebserviceDemo/rest/json/product/dynamicData?size=5");//your url i.e fetch data from .
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in NetClientGet:- " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @OwenIvory what do you mean with apache hell?

Comment: I was initially told to use apache .jar files to accomplish a simple Restful query.  So I downloaded some .jar files, but they were for the wrong version of java (not the one I was using).  Then I found some that were the right version of java, but they were a mismatch of apache version, and thus the classes didn't contain the objects the example I was given had.  Anyway, this example is straight java.net.... i.e. works with just the jdk installed.  No messing with apache versions or acquiring jar files or compile problems, just JDK and go.

Comment: Hi, if my method is a Post and need to send a Json object ¿Is this possible in this method? Regards.

Comment: I'm confused. Which method actually sends the request to the network? Is it `.openConnection()`? If so, why are you setting the request method and headers afterwards?  Forgive me, but I'm still a beginner with java.

Answer (score 19):

As others have said, you can do it using the lower level HTTP API, or you can use the higher level JAXRS APIs to consume a service as JSON. For example:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://host:8080/context/rest/method");
JsonArray response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(JsonArray.class);
```

Comment: As suggested by Holly, JAX RS Client API (introduced in version 2.0) is much better way to consume REST APIs than low level URL +  manual unmarshmaling. I'd suggest to get data as properly mapped Java beans instead of "raw json". A tutorial I wrote about this previously: https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/consuming-rest-services-from-java-applications

Comment: Can i do a POST request with this ? How i set the request's body?

Answer (score 9):

Its just a 2 line of code.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
YourBean obj = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", YourBean.class);
```

[Ref. Spring.io consuming-rest](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/)

Comment: please leave comments why you down-voted the answer.

Comment: You need to use spring web for that since it's using RestTemplate

Comment: Can I use Spring REST Template in JEE, or is there a reason not to?

Comment: @powder366 you can add the required dependencies and use it.

Answer (score 4):

The code below will help to consume rest api via Java. 
**URL** - end point rest 
If you dont need any authentication you dont need to write the **authStringEnd** variable

The method will return a JsonObject with your response

```
public JSONObject getAllTypes() throws JSONException, IOException {
        String url = "/api/atlas/types";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        String authStringEnc = new BASE64Encoder().encode(authString.getBytes());
        javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        WebTarget webTarget = client.target(host + url);
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).header("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
        String output = response.readEntity(String.class
        );

        System.out.println(response.toString());
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(output);

        return obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make an http request to the required URL with correct query string, or request body.

For example you could use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and then consume via `connection.getInputStream()`, and then covnert to your objects.

In spring there is a `restTemplate` that makes it all a bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you also need to convert that xml string that comes as a response to the service call, an x object you need can do it as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class RestServiceClient {

// http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/get
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
SAXException {

try {

URL url = new URL(
    "http://localhost:8080/CustomerDB/webresources/co.com.mazf.ciudad");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
    + conn.getResponseCode());
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    (conn.getInputStream())));

String output;

Ciudades ciudades = new Ciudades();
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println("12132312");
System.err.println(output);

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(output));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
NodeList nodes = ((org.w3c.dom.Document) doc)
    .getElementsByTagName("ciudad");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Ciudad ciudad = new Ciudad();
    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("idCiudad");
    Element element2 = (Element) name.item(0);

    ciudad.setIdCiudad(Integer
        .valueOf(getCharacterDataFromElement(element2)));

    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("nomCiudad");
    element2 = (Element) title.item(0);

    ciudad.setNombre(getCharacterDataFromElement(element2));

    ciudades.getPartnerAccount().add(ciudad);
}
}

for (Ciudad ciudad1 : ciudades.getPartnerAccount()) {
System.out.println(ciudad1.getIdCiudad());
System.out.println(ciudad1.getNombre());
}

conn.disconnect();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
Node child = e.getFirstChild();
if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
return cd.getData();
}
return "";
}
}
```

Note that the xml structure that I expected in the example was as follows:

```
<ciudad><idCiudad>1</idCiudad><nomCiudad>BOGOTA</nomCiudad></ciudad>
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/). Again, REST is all about the data. And a tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)

Comment: that is for producing a restful service

Comment: Not really, with Jersey you don't only produce RESTful web services but also consume them.

Answer (score 1):

[JAX-RS](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs.html) but you can also use regular DOM that comes with standard Java

Answer (score 1):

From your question its not clear whether you are using any frameworks.For REST you will be getting an WADL & Apache CXF recently added support for WADL-first development of REST services.Please go through http://cxf.apache.org/docs/index.html

Comment: Do you mean I can get the Java Classes from WADL?

Answer (score 1):

You can able to consume a Restful Web service in Spring using RestTemplate.class.

Example :

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> call= restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/SpringExample/hello",String.class);
        System.out.println(call.getBody())
    }

}
```

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LGjgU_pFynA)

Comment: you are missing String.class in your  getForEntity

Comment: you didn't add a been class to your response entity.


        ResponseEntity<String> call= restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:8080/SpringExample/hello, String.class");



the it's a String response entity, you supposed to add the bean class String.class as it's second parameter for .getForEntity

Comment: Updated the code

Comment: Can I use Spring REST Template in JEE, or is there a reason not to?

Comment: @powder366 Yes you can use it any java project , all you have to add is the dependency(spring-web) to your project

Answer (score 0):

Apache Http Client APIs are very commonly used for calling HTTP Rest services.

Here is one of example of consuming HTTP GET call.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class CallHTTPGetService {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {


    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = new HttpGet("URL");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpUriRequest);
    System.out.println(response);

}
}
```

Use following maven dependency if using Maven project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```