# Consuming REST web services in Vaadin

Tags: spring, rest, vaadin

How can I create a Vaadin application who consumes a **Restful web Services** ?

My architecture is:

```
.parent project
  .core-subProject (devlopped with spring )
  .ws-subProject (restful web service with jaxb annotation)
  .client-project (using vaadin)
```

thx for help.

Comment: Can you explain better what you've tried and what you want to achieve?

Comment: first of all thank you for replying. then,
I created a core project which contains my entities and services and i test it with Junit. then i created a webservice project (restful WS) which contains the core-project dependancy and i test it with th RestClient plugin in the browser. now i want to consume the webServices in my client project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaadin is a server-side framework, so there is nothing special here, you would do it as in any other Java application.

See for example this question [How to consume REST in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916169/how-to-consume-rest-in-java) or this [Vaadin forum post](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/79389).

Basically, you need to create a RESTful URI, open a stream to it and parse it. If the output is XML possibly with something like [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).