# How to consume Rest services in ATG?

Tags: atg

I have gone through the ATG oracle guide for rest web service Architecture. Kindly provide a basic example/ steps to consume a rest service in oracle ATG.

Comment: ATG runs on JAVA. Plenty of examples of consuming REST services in JAVA. Even on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916169/how-to-consume-rest-in-java

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to consume an external REST API from within your ATG application, then ATG does not provide you any specific way to do so, but ATG is Java, and there are many ways to call REST services in Java.

If you are looking to expose REST APIs from your ATG application, then ATG 9 onwards has a REST Services framework, and ATG 11 onwards has a REST MVC framework that you can use. If these are not suitable for you, then there are other, third-party, ways of doing it too.