# Generating java class(model) from WADL url

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services

I have wadl url from where need to generates java class for consuming rest web services.

How can I create java class from that wadl?
Thanks.

Comment: Check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916169/how-to-consume-rest-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look to 
[CXF JAX-RS](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html).

CXF JAX-RS supports Web Application Description Language (WADL) and is very well documented.